# "Message not sent!" when running sentry:test command

Tags: php, symfony, sentry

I'm trying to add Sentry to a Symfony application, but I can't get the Sentry client to actually send anything to Sentry. I've followed the instructions by running `composer require sentry/sentry-symfony`, adding the DSN to my `.env` file, adding this controller;

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SentryTestController
{
    #[Route(path: 'sentry_test')]
    public function test()
    {
        throw new Exception('test');
    }
}
```

and going to the `sentry_test` page. While the exception is thrown, nothing appears in Sentry.

The Sentry bundle has been added to `bundles.php` as `Sentry\SentryBundle\SentryBundle::class => ['all' => true]`, I've tried setting `APP_ENV=prod` and `APP_DEBUG=false`, but it still doesn't work.

Running `php bin/console sentry:test` (which got added as a command after installing `sentry/sentry-symfony`) results in

```
DSN correctly configured in the current client
Sending test message...
Message not sent!
<warning>Check your DSN or your before_send callback if used</warning>
```

Anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After diving into the source code for both `sentry/sentry` and `sentry/sentry-symfony`, I came across a cURL HTTP error. After googling that specific error the fix was quite simple; `composer update "sentry/*" -W` to update all Sentry packages and their dependencies. I figured running `composer require sentry/...` would install the latest available version, but apparently it did not.

Sentry works properly now.